# Garbage values in floating point number

Tags: java, sql, swing, h2

I'm working on java(swing) which is connected to database on H2. I've attached a screenshot of the JFrame, i'm entering values as a user and in database its storing some garbage value. (refer in the database screen shot, second column where empid=1300)

[image: JFrame screenshot with the values]

[image: Screenshot of the database]

Comment: Required Reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and 
[Is Floating Point Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/18157)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because they can't be accurately represented and you should use `BigDecimal` in java and `DECIMAL` in SQL. Refer here http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#decimal_type. It says:

> DECIMAL type: Data type with fixed precision and scale. This data type
>   is recommended for storing currency values.
>
> DOUBLE type: A floating point number. Should not be used to represent
>   currency values, because of rounding problems. If precision value is
>   specified for FLOAT type name, it should be from 25 to 53.